# Can I freeze the data I have in a PowerBI Dataset to use it offline?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a power BI dataset that takes its data from a software made by the IT team in my organization.
I was wondering if it was possible for me to "freeze" all the data in the PBI dataset (like, taking a picture of the data for exemple today) and use this dataset for further analysis (I have another power BI file linked to that Power BI dataset). I know the data won't refresh, but it's not important for what I need to do, as I only need to have the past info.
The reason why I need to know if that's possible is that I'm going oversea for one month and won't have access to the original dataset. Downloading all the data into one excel is impossible as it is way to big.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're after some sort of snapshotting functionality
If you just wanted to keep the file as is, then you can download the pbix and just not refresh it provided its in import mode.

However one approach you could take if you want to continue doing development without worrying about accidentally refreshing is to use a power bi dataflow

You could copy your power query queries to a dataflow. Refresh them all as at today. Then don't refresh the dataflow anymore

You can then point your power bi dataset to your dataflow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-create

That way if you wanted to do further transformation of data, you wouldnt be getting new data from the data source (so long as you dont refresh the dataflow)